# docx4j: pdf export adds leading spaces

Tags: apache-fop, docx4j

Wile exporting a simple docx file to pdf, docx4j is adding leading spaces (see: picture). I use following libraries:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>docx4j</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>docx4j-export-fo</artifactId>
        <version>8.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

[image: generated pdf]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is caused by https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-export-FO/commit/4451111aa02a698ed54788299513f7eac74bd996 which will need to be reverted.

Comment: docx4j-export-fo 6.1.0 seems fine. Are you planning to fix that bug potentially in 8.1.4? And possibly when?

Comment: @PawelNieradka yes, have a patch to apply.  December.