# Docx4j docx toPdf don't preserve whitespaces

Tags: java, docx4j, pdf-conversion, trailing-whitespace, docx-to-pdf-conversion

i have a problem with docx4j. The output pdf is cutted and all spaces or tabs are now replaced with only one. For example if in the docx there is a string like
"  a            a                  a"
the output will be "a a a". Same with tabs. My code and my pom below. What am i doing wrong? Thank you.

```
           InputStream isNodo = new ByteArrayInputStream(contentNodoTempl);

            WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(isNodo);
            VariablePrepare.prepare(wordMLPackage);

            // output file
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            Docx4J.toPDF(wordMLPackage, bos);
            bos.flush();
            isNodo.close();
            return bos.toByteArray();
```

With my pom looking like

```
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
         <artifactId>docx4j-JAXB-ReferenceImpl</artifactId>
         <version>8.3.9</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
         <artifactId>docx4j-export-fo</artifactId>
         <version>8.3.9</version>
      </dependency>
```

i have tried with t.setSpace("preserve") (code below) but the spaces are still cutted.

```
    public static void findAndReplace(WordprocessingMLPackage doc){
        List<Object> paragraphs = getAllElementFromObject(doc.getMainDocumentPart(), P.class);
        for(Object par : paragraphs){
            P p = (P) par;
            List<Object> texts = getAllElementFromObject(p, Text.class);
            for(Object text : texts){
                Text t = (Text)text;
                t.setSpace("preserve");
            }
        }
    }

    public static List<Object> getAllElementFromObject(Object obj, Class<?> toSearch) {
        List<Object> result = new ArrayList<Object>();
        if (obj instanceof JAXBElement) obj = ((JAXBElement<?>) obj).getValue();

        if (obj.getClass().equals(toSearch))
            result.add(obj);
        else if (obj instanceof ContentAccessor) {
            List<?> children = ((ContentAccessor) obj).getContent();
            for (Object child : children) {
                result.addAll(getAllElementFromObject(child, toSearch));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [docx4j - Why is the text truncated of spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27400878/docx4j-why-is-the-text-truncated-of-spaces)

Comment: No, i'm already doing t.setSpace("preserve"); but still no right result. In this post that you have linked the problem is when creating text part, in my case i have to update my text part and not create new ones.

Comment: thing is, the software producing the xml might be doing weird thing by [forgetting preserve flag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70292576). that or the particular docx4j had a bug, [happened before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58802818/docx4j-pdf-export-adds-leading-spaces). maybe you should inspect the docx file, both the original and the one you added `t.setSpace(..`.

Comment: i have inspected the docx file that i give in input and right before the spaces there is
<w:t xml:space="preserve"> so the problem is in my code or it is a problem with docx4j.